# Javascript: Finding index of an object in an array, based on a value within a nested array on the objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[{
    name: 'foobar',
    fields: [{
        label: 'argle'
    },{
        label: 'bargle'
    }]
},{
    name: 'baz',
    fields: [{
        label: 'rar'
    },{
        label: 'hoogah'
    }]
}]
```

I'm looking for the *index* of the object which has a `field` matching `label === 'rar'`, so I can update that particular field.  Is there an optimum way to accomplish this? I know `indexOf` won't get me there by itself, but I'm struggling with the logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) methods of Array.

```
[
    {name: 'foobar', fields: [{label: 'argle'}, {label: 'bargle'}]},
    {name: 'baz', fields: [{label: 'rar'}, {label: 'hoogah'}]}
].findIndex(function(element, index, array) {
   return element.fields.some(function(element, index, array) {
     return element.label === 'rar';
   });
})
```

returns    1

Answer (score 2):

With [***arrow functions***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you can do the searches shown in [Mathieu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37287001/1615483) nice and cleanly

```
let arr = [
  {name: 'foobar', fields: [{label: 'argle'}, {label: 'bargle'}]},
  {name: 'baz', fields: [{label: 'rar'}, {label: 'hoogah'}]}
];
```

Then

```
arr.findIndex(item => item.fields.some(deepItem => deepItem.label === 'rar')); // 1
```

---

If you're more interested in accessing the item itself, not it's index, then use [`arr.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead

```
arr.find(item => item.fields.some(deepItem => deepItem.label === 'rar')); // Object
```

---

Further, if you want every item which matches, then use [`arr.fileter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead

```
arr.filter(item => item.fields.some(deepItem => deepItem.label === 'rar')); // [{...}, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

an ugly way of doing it.

```
var data = [
  {name: 'foobar', fields: [{label: 'argle'}, {label: 'bargle'}]},
  {name: 'baz', fields: [{label: 'rar'}, {label: 'hoogah'}]}
],

i = data.findIndex(e => ~e.fields.findIndex(f => f.label == 'rar'));
// returns 1
```

Answer (score 0):

a 'normal' way of doing it:

```
var arr = [
  {name: 'foobar', fields: [{label: 'argle'}, {label: 'bargle'}]},
  {name: 'baz', fields: [{label: 'rar'}, {label: 'hoogah'}]},
  {name: 'foo', fields: [{label: 'asjda'}, {label: 'hoogah'}]}
];

function findByLabel(arr, str) {
  var res = null;
  arr.forEach(function(item) { 
      if (item.fields[0].label == 'rar')
          res = item
  });
  return res;
} 

console.log(findByLabel(arr, 'rar'));
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5h8ugasf/4/